# Adding links in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How can I add a link in my Jupiter notebook as part of a Markdown cell? Specifically, how can I make a word such as 'email' a link to my email, or 'YouTube' a link to my YouTube account?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's just standard markdown (as in stackoverflow):

```
[YouTube](https://youtube.com)
```

would give you [YouTube](https://youtube.com).